# Cannot init AwesomeProject React Native

Tags: react-native

I followed all step in [React Native - Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). I typed

```
> react-native init AwesomeProject
```

and got the following error

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in 
/Users/invisal/Documents/React/AwesomeProject

Installing react-native package from npm...

npm ERR! Error: Invalid name: "AwesomeProject"
....
```

I am running OS X El Capitan 10.1. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this one?

Comment: Do you had have a AwesomeProject under the same document path?

Comment: @KChen, Yes. I tried one without AwesomeProject, and one without. Got the same error.

Comment: Maybe there's some errors with `npm install -g react-native-cli`. Try to install again and check if there are errors. Or try another project name and check if there is the same error.